# ArcGIS Server 9.3 - Javascript API - Selecting Feature Problem

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-9.3

I have ArcGIS Server 9.3, and I'm trying to use the JS API. I successfully displayed the map, and I can locate and zoom to a feature based on ParcelID value. The problem is I can't highlight this parcel. I mean I tried to configure the symbol, but its not being displayed. Here's the code:

```
<script>

    dojo.require("esri.map");
    dojo.require("esri.layers.FeatureLayer");
    var map,featureLayer,query,sfs;

  function init() {
    map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", { 
      sliderOrientation: "horizontal"
    }); 


    var imageParameters = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
    imageParameters.format = "PNG24";  //set the image type to PNG24, note default is PNG8.

    //Takes a URL to a non cached map service.
    var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://*******/*****/rest/services/****/MapServer", {
      "opacity":1, 
      "imageParameters":imageParameters
    });
    dynamicMapServiceLayer.setVisibleLayers([4,10,11,16]);
    map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);


    //Locate Parcel--------
    sfs = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2),new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.25]));

    featureLayer  = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://*****/*****/rest/services/*****/MapServer/4", {
            outFields: ["*"],
            mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION
        });
    featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(sfs);
    map.addLayers([featureLayer]);

    query = new esri.tasks.Query();        
    query.where = "ParcelID_NS = '101010101'";

    var deferred = featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (selection) {
        var stateExtent = selection[0].geometry.getExtent().expand(3.0);
        map.setExtent(stateExtent);
    });
    //----------------------    
  }


  dojo.ready(init);

</script>
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Your code is almost correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var deferred = featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (selection) {
    var stateExtent = selection[0].geometry.getExtent().expand(3.0);
    map.setExtent(stateExtent);
```

try this  instead of

```
 featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
```

You can get the selected features from featurelayer.FeatureSelection() method available which will return as Graphics from that you do getExtent().expand(3.0);

Comment: I can't see any deference ?

Comment: Try the updated one once. For me its worked fine.

Comment: Is it worked for you